# VB.net how to reset a form?

Tags: vb.net

I wanna know if it's posible to reset a form? I'm making a battle game but i need to reset the form after a battle so i can play the battle infinity times

Maybe something a little like this:

```
    If TextBox1.Text = "You Won!" Then
        Me.reset
    End If
```

Of course this dosen't work that is why im asking for help to reset the form.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"? You probably need to write some code for a reset method to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very simple solution is to just create a new instance of the form and closing the "used" one. Greatly assisted by the Project + Properties, Shutdown mode setting. Change it to "When last form closes".  Which makes this code work:

```
If Me.TextBox1.Text = "You Won!" Then
    Dim frm = New Form1               '' Change the class name if necessary
    frm.Show()
    Me.Close()
End If
```

Comment: Just to add to your answer, make sure that the form isn't the parent/Startup form. otherwise, the program will terminate. 
I recommend using MDI Forms for this very reason.

Comment: Ah, guess mine's an alternative then.

Answer (score 4):

**The Easiest way**

call from the form you want to reset/restart

---form name---

application.restart

me.refresh

that will do the magic. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Of course this dosen't work that is why im asking for help to reset the form. Thanks!

There is no built in method to do this.  You would need to write a `Reset` method on your form, which would go through and setup all of the properties and values back to their original state.

Comment: Thanks! My brother know how to do that so he's gonna help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset a form that can be re-opened from another form later on, you need a slight tweak:

```
Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
        Dim f2 As New client1Form
        Me.Dispose()  '~~> Or Me.Close()
        f2.Show()
        starterForm.currentForm = f2
    End Sub
```

- We make the new form, `f2` then dispose of the current one.

- We then show the new `f2` form and set the `currentForm` (`Dim currentForm As Form`) to equal the new `f2` form so that when we
  click on the button which handles the opening of the original `client1Form`, it will open this new `f2`, **instead of the old one which we got 
  rid of** with `Me.dispose()` or `Me.Close()`.

- Without the `starterForm.currentForm = f2`, when we re-open the form, **it'll just give you the original you had before**, including any data that remained, if you used `Me.Close()`)   or just an empty version of the original form, (if you used `Me.Dispose()`). But we want then new form & any data we enter into it.

- On the parent form we are using `currentForm.Show()` on the click event of the open form button.