# Reset windows form without exiting the program

Tags: vb.net

hello all? is there any way to completely reset a form on close or dispose?
I mean when you exit entire program everything will reset right.? so I want that without closing first form but closing only second one should do..!! Thanks

Comment: This has been asked before: [VB.net How to Reset a Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779664/vb-net-how-to-reset-a-form)

Comment: It doesn't what i want sir, what i want is, example: i have 2 forms, Mainform and Form1 when the program starts, main form is shown, then i have button to show form1 and input something in there, then when i close form1 then open it again, i want those text i input will be cleared without making a command like 'text.clear' i just want to load the form1 again like it was first load. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I misunderstood your question. In that case, you can use ShowDialog in Form1 like so:

```
Dim Cancel As Boolean = False 'you can set this true using whatever event suits your needs

While Not Cancel
    Using newform2 As New Form2
        newform2.ShowDialog()
    End Using
Loop
```

If I'm understanding what you need right, the code above will just keep opening new instances of that form until you tell it to stop. Honestly though, I really think you should consider having the form reset itself instead of closing and reopening it. If the form is coded in a modular way and most (or all) variables are of limited scope, then doing so should not require much code. Hope that helps though

Comment: i got it sir, but isn't it resets on its another load? is there a way to reset on its form close? because sir i'm using fingerprintscanner, and its method in verification finger as login, then i cant register new fingerprint because of the verification method in login form is still working, that is why i need to reset the login form in its form close. thanks.

Comment: Then just throw it inside a loop if you need it to keep opening as soon as the previous form closes(edit above). Then, whenever you want to truly stop it from opening, you just use a button or event or whatever to set Cancel = True

Answer (score 0):

When you call it from your main form, let say it was something like this:

Private Sub Button1_Click()

Form1.Show

'when Form1 close

'just put this

Form1.Dispose()   'this will reset everything

End Sub

Comment: no sir, it will not reset, even the texts you input in a text field will still there when you open it again.

Comment: dispose() should remove all resource on that form, it's always work for me, you should debug your code, and run it step by step